# Storing a callback function in a variable gives an error

Tags: php

I am studying the book "Programming PHP 3rd edition", and I came upon these lines go code:

```
$callback = function myCallbackFunction()
{
echo "callback achieved";

} call_user_func($callback);
```

But, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'myCallbackFunction' (T_STRING), expecting'('
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is the code incorrect?
And here is my PHP version:

```
% php -v                                                                                                                  255 ↵
PHP 5.4.19 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2013 14:26:26)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v2.0.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.5.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous functions don't have a function name. That's why they are called *anonymous*. The definition should look like this:

```
$callback = function ()
{
    echo "callback achieved";
};

call_user_func($callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you define an [anonymous](http://www.php.net//manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) function or a [non-anonymous.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

To define a anoymous, what are you obivously trying to do, you shouldn't put a name before the argument list `()`

```
$callback = function()
{
echo "callback achieved";

};
call_user_func($callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to create an anonymous function.

```
$callback = function()
{
    echo "callback achieved";
}

call_user_func($callback);
```

Try removing the functions name.

If you are trying to call an existing function, then you can do it like this:

```
function myCallbackFunction()
{
    echo "callback achieved";
}

call_user_func('myCallbackFunction');
```